# What is the purpose of these lines of assembly code?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, compiler-construction, x86

```
_main:
; create stack frame
pushl   %ebp
movl    %esp, %ebp
; save one local variable
subl    $8, %esp
; zero four rightmost bits of esp
andl    $-16, %esp
; set eax to (0 + 15 + 15) / 2^4 * 2^4 = 16
movl    $0, %eax
addl    $15, %eax
addl    $15, %eax
shrl    $4, %eax
sall    $4, %eax
; set local variable to eax (16)
movl    %eax, -4(%ebp)
movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
; call allocation and main
call    __alloca
call    ___main
; set eax to zero (return value)
movl    $0, %eax
; fold stack frame and return to caller
leave
ret
```

I compiled a `int main(){return 0;}` C code using `gcc -S return_zero.c` (on Windows) and this is what I got (I removed the assembler directives and added explanation comment as much as I understood. Correct me if I'm wrong, please.).

I don't understand three things:

- Why does the compiler align esp to 16?
- Why is eax set to 16, why it is done in such a complicated way, and why is there a local variable also set to 16?
- What are __alloca and ___main?

I got somewhat unclear explanations to both #1 and #3 on the internet so I'd like if someone can answer more deeply and for #2 I haven't find any explanation so if someone can explain it'll be great.

If any further information is needed comment and I'll post it.

Thanks!

Comment: Try compiling with optimizations.

Comment: @KerrekSB
I compiled with -O3.  
It removed the whole eax = 16 thing and uses xorl instead of movl to set eax to 0 at the end but it still does all the other stuff (including declaring a local variable).  
Also I'm curious why it does this anyway.

Comment: What platform is this for? I can't reproduce this on Linux.

Comment: @KerrekSB I'm using Windows 8.1 with Intel Core i5.

Comment: Checkout the Windows ABI, specifically register spilling and red zones.

Comment: @KerrekSB Thanks. So it's connected to the `call __alloca`? I still don't get why would it have the value of 16.

Comment: The call to `__alloca` allocates space on the stack. It's necessary when the amount being allocate on the stack could be over 4092 bytes. It's not necessary here. The call `___main` is for initialization that needs to be done before the start of the program. It shouldn't be necessary, as this initialization should have been done be `_main` was called. These are probably artifacts of the MinGW port of GCC which has issues like these.

Comment: @RossRidge OK, thanks!

Comment: My guess here is that you would get more information if your main function had arguments. I suspect that what you are seeing comes from a main template that will do processing for arguments.

Answer (score 1):

The *Intel Core i5* uses a 64 bit architecture.
Addressing questions 1, and partially 2, From *[an Overview of x64 Calling Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx)*:

> Alignment
>   Most structures are aligned to their natural alignment. The primary
>   exceptions are the stack pointer and malloc or alloca memory, which
>   are aligned to 16 bytes in order to aid performance. Alignment above
>   16 bytes must be done manually, but since 16 bytes is a common
>   alignment size for XMM operations, this should work for most code. For
>   more information about structure layout and alignment see Types and
>   Storage. For information about the stack layout, see Stack Usage.

regarding the part of your question: *...why it is done in such a complicated way*.  Only a guess, but from the quote, the complexity may be due in part to accommodate portability.

Borrowing from *[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/823452/645128)*, (also having tags `gcc`, `compiler-construction` &  `assembly` ) is a very good line by line explanation of some of the same code you are trying to interpret.  An excerpt:

> In step 1 we save the pointer to the old stack frame on the stack by
>   calling, pushl %ebp. Since main is the first function called, I have
>   no idea what the previous value of %ebp points too.
>
> Step 2, We are entering a new stack frame because we are entering a
>   new function (main). Therefore, we must set a new stack frame base
>   pointer. We use the value in esp to be the beginning of our stack
>   frame.
>
> Step 3. Allocates 8 bytes of space on the stack. As we mentioned
>   above, the stack grows toward lower addresses thus, subtracting by 8,
>   moves the top of the stack by 8 bytes.
>   ...

and regarding calling __alloca & __main

> ...
>   Steps 12 and 13 setup the c library.

Comment: OK, so the aligning is some kind of Windows convention? But I still don't get the eax and local variable part. Are they some kind of argument to __alloca? This doesn't make sense.

Comment: But it doesn't hold the former value of `esp`, it holds the value of 16, doesn't it?

Comment: Neo - _subl    $8, %esp_ Here, the compiler appears to be reserving space on the stack. I am not sure why it reserves 8.  Again, likely directly related to alignment.  It probably will contain left most bits of esp after clearing the rightmost bits.

Comment: So it's some kind of argument for `__alloca`?

Comment: @Neo - `andl    $-16, %esp`  aligns esp to a 16 byte boundary.  ( from references _[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23309863/why-does-gcc-produce-andl-16)_ and _[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465232/what-does-subl-do-here)_ )

Comment: @Neo - the link (and an excerpt) edited into my answer above details some answers to similar questions you are asking. Hope it helps. ( I am very new to assembly. )