# What happens to EBP when calling a function

Tags: gdb, stack-frame

This is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test_function(int a, int b, int c, int d){

    int flag;   
    flag = 31337;

}

int main(){

    test_function(1,2,3,4);
}
```

From GDB:

```
    Breakpoint 1, main () at stack_example.c:14
    14      test_function(1,2,3,4);
    (gdb) i r esp ebp eip
    esp            0xffffcf88   0xffffcf88
    ebp            0xffffcf98   0xffffcf98
    eip            0x8048402    0x8048402 <main+6>
    (gdb) cont
    Continuing.

    Breakpoint 2, test_function (a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4) at stack_example.c:8
    8       flag = 31337;
    (gdb) i r esp ebp eip
    esp            0xffffcf70   0xffffcf70
    ebp            0xffffcf80   0xffffcf80
    eip            0x80483f3    0x80483f3 <test_function+6>
    (gdb) 

Dump of assembler code for function test_function:
   0x080483ed <+0>: push   ebp
   x080483ee <+1>:  mov    ebp,esp
   0x080483f0 <+3>: sub    esp,0x10
=> 0x080483f3 <+6>: mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4],0x7a69
   0x080483fa <+13>:    leave  
   0x080483fb <+14>:    ret
```

From GDB, 
Why does EBP not have the same value as what ESP was in main()? Shouldn't `mov ebp, esp`
make EBP == `0xffffcf88`? I thought this sets EBP to what ESP is.

**EDIT:**

I think I may have answered my own question. Please correct me. 
ESP is moved when the return address and saved frame pointer are pushed onto the stack.

The `ESP` value was `0xffffcf88` before the two values(both 4 bytes) were pushed onto the stack. Afterwards, it's value is `0xffffcf88 - 0x8` == `0xffffcf80`. This is what EBP's current value is. Then ESP -= 0x10.

How is the value of ESP modified? Is it something like `mov ESP, ESP - 0x8` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understand your question.

First, you are correct about new value of frame pointer. Here you need to know that "break test_function" actually stops gdb after the function prologue has been executed, so you are already past the point where ebp is explicitly stored to stack.
See [detailed explanation](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/win32-callconv-asm.html).

ESP is decreased by four for every push (or call). It's also decreased (some immediate value subtracted) by the amount of space required by the local variables, etc.
[Different "calling conventions" are being used on x86](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions), so these details may vary a bit.

Some parts of this are also compiler specific. For example GCC by default keeps stack 4-word aligned on x86 (for one reason to keep SSE unit happy). See [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061818/stack-allocation-padding-and-alignment).

BTW: frame pointer is actually redundant as long as compiler knows how to unwind stack from any point in function and it is typically omitted with optimized code.