# Stack Alignment - Buffer Overflow Testing

Tags: c, gcc, stack-overflow, buffer-overflow, stack-frame

I've done a lot of research trying to understand this topic but still have some confusion. Currently I'm investigating buffer overflow. Here's an example of the function I'm looking at:

```
int testFunction(char* sourceBuffer)
{
    unsigned char result = 0;
    char destinationBuffer[512];

    //do some insecure stuff with strcpy()
}
```

I'm compiling with these settings:

```
gcc -g -z execstack -fno-stack-protector -o test test.c
```

From what I can tell ASLR, stack protection, canary values, and compiler guards should be disabled with these settings. However upon inspecting memory in GDB this is how my stack looks:

```
HIGH

sourceBuffer...temp...etc...
RET address [4 bytes]
EBP address [4 bytes]

(8 bytes of mystery memory)

result [1 byte]
destinationBuffer[512 bytes]

LOW
```

I've tried reading about stack alignment / padding, this article was particularly helpful: [Stack allocation, padding, and alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061818/stack-allocation-padding-and-alignment)

The default alignment is 16-bytes. According to that answer, if I change n = 2 it looks like it works. `result` is just 1 byte before where `EBP` pointer starts. This will allow me to exploit the buffer overflow into the return address like I want.

I'm really having a hard time how this works. If by default it's 16, is the stack initially setup with 16 bytes, then the RET and EBP pointers take up 4 bytes each, so there's just 8 bytes left over? I'm just pretty lost on understanding this.

Comment: What is "n"? You say "if I change n = 2" but that "n" is nowhere mentioned throughout the rest of the question. And what is your question? You are not really asking any question above. Is your question why there are 8 bytes padding? If so, please also ask that question.

Answer (score 1):

Your stack seems to be 16 byte aligned. If there are 4 bytes RET and 4 bytes EBP, then you will of course need another 8 bytes padding to uphold that 16 bytes alignment, otherwise your local function storage would not start at a multiple of 16 byte and then your stack wasn't 16 byte aligned.